# One of my member functions, which is a purely virtual void, has an LNK 2019 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, polymorphism, virtual-functions, lnk2019

I am working on drawing shapes using strings with C++. So I wrote a class of Shapes that serves as a base class to 2 derived classes, which are Diamond and Square. My virtual void function setStars() basically stores the coordinates of the points of the shape that I am going to print on a board of strings. Nevertheless, the function is involved with a LNK 2019 problem which I have no idea why. This is my code for the base class.

```
#ifndef _SHAPE_
#define _SHAPE_

#include <utility>
#include <vector>

class Shape {
protected:
    int x, y, sz;//x-coordinate, y-coordinate, size of Shape


public:
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> listOfPoints;
    Shape(int xPos, int yPos, int size) : x(xPos), y(yPos), sz(size) { setStars(); }
    virtual void setStars() = 0;
    void moveBy(int xMove, int yMove) {
        x += xMove;
        y += yMove;
        setStars();
    }
    void setSize(int size) {
        sz = size;
        setStars();
    }
    virtual ~Shape() = default;

};

#endif
```

The setStars() function is defined in the other derived classes. But I get this error:

```
unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Shape::setStars(void)" (?setStars@Shape@@UAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Shape::Shape(int,int,int)" (??0Shape@@QAE@HHH@Z)
```

Can someone explain to me what is wrong?

Comment: You can’t call a virtual function of a derived class in the constructor of the base.

Comment: @manni66 you mean in the moveBy and setSize functions?But I commented them and the problem still persists

Comment: Why should I call these functions constructor?

Comment: @manni66 I see. Sorry for misunderstanding.